# How to correctly check FileStreamWriter is in use?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2015

I am using a System::IO::StreamWriter. My intention is to check if the file in use is open, and close it.

What is the correct way of checking if the file is in use. I keep getting System.NullReferenceException with the code below.

```
if (filewr2->BaseStream != nullptr)
{
    filewr2->Close();
    filewr2 = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I think that mean your `filewr2` is `null`

Comment: It is just a basic misunderstanding, you cannot forcibly close a file that is in use.  The OS does not allow that.  Could be that the file is used by another process, you have no other option but to try later or tell the user about it.  Could be a bug in your own program, a common one, it is a very easy to forget to close or dispose a StreamReader/Writer.